# How to model a Dome with Cylinders?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How can I model this, . I've only started to try, but im a newbie and feel like I'mma fail at making it look like a dome with the curvature. Any advice or comment would be much appreciated! :) [image: Dome with cylinders]

The "progress"
[image: "Progress"]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with face instancing.

1. Parent the Cylinder to the Dome
2. Select the Dome and go *Object Tab > Instancing > Faces*
3. Done

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative with geometry nodes. Create your dome, create your cylinder. Give your dome a *Geometry Node* modifier with this setup: *Group Input > (Point) Align Rotation to Vector* (with *Vector > Attribute*, and *Vector > Position) > (Point) > Point Instance* (with the cylinder as *Object) > Output.*

[image]

Comment: and the master strikes back again....! :D

Comment: well I'm more like a monkey randomly trying some things  ;)

Comment: :D yeah, but i monkey with a lot of knowledge of Blender...! ;)