# Blender exporting hidden layer?

Tags: objects

I did this with Instancing on faces in object properties
[image: what i want]

But when I export it as OBJ. It looks with the sphere I first created. I just need this for a photoshop art im making, but im so noob at blender

[image: How it looks]

Comment: Even tho display instancer its not checked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, I created this with the help of this question 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217799/how-to-model-a-dome-with-cylinders